# How do I filter out a key from an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have following object in JS. How can I select all keys except the first `financial_year` and put it into a new empty object?

I understand I can do something like `obj["mainline_revenue"]` to select individual elements but its a long list and I don't want to type elements keys individually.

```
var obj = {financial_year: 1, mainline_revenue: 18743, regional_revenue: 2914, other_revenue: 3198, salaries_wages: -6897}

var newObj = {}
```

New object would look like this:

```
console.log(newObj)
{mainline_revenue: 18743, regional_revenue: 2914, other_revenue: 3198, salaries_wages: -6897}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just clone the object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) then use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) to removed the undesired property:

```
var newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
delete newObj.financial_year;
```

Of course there are other more functional ways to achieve this, maybe by filtering the keys, then reducing to an object:

```
var newObj = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => 
  key !== 'financial_year'
).reduce((newObj, currKey) =>
  (newObj[currKey] = obj[currKey], newObj), 
{});
```

Though this approach would be more suited if you had *an array of keys* you wanted to filter out, and you could just check if the key was in the array in the `filter` callback.

Answer (score 0):

1. The **Object.keys()** method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property names.
2. The **forEach()** method executes a provided function once for each array element (iterate thorough an array).

   const newFilteredObj = {}

   ```
   Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
     if (key !== "financial_year") {
       newFilteredObj[key] = obj[key]
     }
   })
   ```